# Why restricting file size validation is not working using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried a lot on searching but could not find a working script for the limitation of the file size using javascript here below is my code but it is not working

```
   if ($('#photo').get(0).files.size >1024 ) 
       {

                 alert("Please select pic size less than  1 mb file .");
                 return false;
    }
```

Where photo is id of input type file

Comment: `files[0].size`

Comment: `size` is in bytes. you need to divide it by 1024 to get KB and 1024 again to get MB. Ignoring the syntax error your code validates that the file is < 1KB

Comment: Liam , I have to divide it or multiply ?

Comment: 1mB = 1,048,576 bytes or you can write 1024 * 1024

Comment: thanks I  did not put [0]  after files , It worked and thanks Curlas

Answer (score 0):

There was some mistake Which I have forgot thanks for helping me Here is my updated answer

```
              if ($('#photo').get(0).files[0].size >1048576 ) {
             alert("Please select pic size less than  1mb file .");
             return false;
                }
```